# In Gmail Addons, how to get access to all threads' details returned by GmailApp.search?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

With the following method, I get the error:

> "Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetThread"

at the `var button [...]` line.

```js
function createItemListCard() {
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Item list'));
    var section = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("<b>Items</b>");
    var threads = GmailApp.search("some search query")
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()).setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(threads[i].getPermalink()));
    }
    return card.build();
}
```

Example code snipplets seem to be using access tokens per message, like:

```
var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
```

But it does not help at all. Most likely due to accessing all threads not just a single message. The scope mentioned in docs for `search` is in place: `https://mail.google.com/`

There must be a way to access results of `GmailApp.search` in Gmail Addons. **How to do it**?

Comment: What’s the sense od GmailApp.search existence, then?

Comment: Request a more permissive scope.

Comment: More permissive than `https://mail.google.com/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
```

to the scopes in your manifest.

What might not be obvious is that you'll need to REMOVE

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly
```

from the manifest. It appears that the apps script environment chooses the most restrictive set of permissions from the scopes available: if you have both scopes in your manifest you will only get the current.message.readonly permission (and you won't be able to interact with any other messages).

I also found that I needed to completely uninstall the addon and then re-install it to get the new scopes to take effect.