# Google Apps Scripts -- Using getdraft() method not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

Trying to extend the compose UI to get some information from drafts, When I try to get the draft using draft.getMessage().getBody(), I have this error:

```
Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetMessage. [line: 19, function: validateRecipients, file: Code]
```

My code:

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
var content = draft.getMessage().getBody();
draft.update("blabla@gmail.com", "Disclosure Alert", "The below message is flagged as possible data disclosure.\n Recipients:"+allEmails+"\n Content:\n"+content);
draft.send();
```

My Manifest Scopes:

```
  "oauthScopes" : [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute"
    ]
```

Comment: Hey @Sherif, is my answer what you were looking for? Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 -- I haven't tried it yet, I'll try it and let you know ASAP. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple scopes in an add-on, **the most restrictive scopes possible will be automatically selected** (See related question: [In Gmail Addons, how to get access to all threads' details returned by GmailApp.search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298398/in-gmail-addons-how-to-get-access-to-all-threads-details-returned-by-gmailapp)).

Since you are already using the least restrictive GMail scope (`https://mail.google.com/`) I suggest you change your manifest scopes to the following (Notice removed `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.*` scopes):

```js
"oauthScopes" : [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute"
]
```

If you consider publishing this add-on, bear in mind that you will not be allowed the `https://mail.google.com` scope, so you may be interested in checking out other scopes such as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`.

### Reference

- [GMail add-on scopes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/scopes#gmail_add-on_scopes).